# Unable to get or create object within a form

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views

I am trying to get or create an object when another one is created with a form :

```
def index(request, log_id, token):
log = get_object_or_404(LogBook, pk=log_id)
logmessages = LogMessage.objects.filter(logbook=log_id)
form = CreateLogMessage(request.POST)
if request.method == "POST":
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.reported_by = request.user
        instance.logbook = log
        instance.save()
        logdone = LogDone.objects.get_or_create(logmessage=logmessages, done_status=False)
```

I am trying to figure out a way to get the id of the logmessage created to pass it to my logdone instance.

I don't find a way to do it so far, any help will be appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

The object that is created is the instance, you thus can implement this as:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def index(request, log_id, token):
    log = get_object_or_404(LogBook, pk=log_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateLogMessage(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.reported_by = request.user
            form.instance.logbook = log
            instance = form.save()
            logdone = LogDone.objects.get_or_create(
                logmessage=instance,
                done_status=False
            )
            return redirect('name-of-some-view')
    else:
        form = CreateLogMessage(request.POST)
        …
```

Since your form creates a *new* object every time, this however *always* create an object.

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

Comment: As always thanks for your clear answer and the tips that help me (and other) improve their code, i will have a look at the doc and improve the overall script.